# R Shiny and Tabulator

Tags: r, shiny, tabulator

I've searched for "r shiny tabulator" and expected more results than zero. Is embedding a Tabulator in R Shiny apps at all possible? Can Tabulator events be sent back to R?

I've created a sample tabulator. The test app below contains all the jQuery references we use in another app but I'm not sure if they are required in R.

Where to take it from there to initialize and show the two rows of sample data in tabulatorDiv?

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

tabulatorClass <- 
"class AIClass {
    doLoad() {
        const sampleData = [
            { AI: 'Substance2', AIGroup: 'GroupA', Volume: 1.23, Price: 4.56, Included: true },
            { AI: 'Substance1', AIGroup: 'GroupB', Volume: 3.21, Price: 6.54, Included: true },
        ];

        this.aiTableCopy = structuredClone(sampleData);
        this.aiTableCopy.forEach(a => a.newRow = false);

        const aiTableCopyTemp = structuredClone(this.aiTableCopy);

        if (!this.aiTable) {
            this.aiTable = new Tabulator('#tabulatorDiv', {
                columns: [
                    { title: 'AI', field: 'AI', width: 100 },
                    { title: 'AIGroup', field: 'AIGroup', width: 100 },
                    { title: 'Volume', field: 'Volume', width: 100 },
                    { title: 'Price', field: 'Price', width: 100 },
                    { title: 'Included', field: 'Included', width: 75 }
                ],
                initialSort: [{ column: 'AI', dir: 'asc' }],
                data: aiTableCopyTemp
            });
            this.aiTable.on('cellEdited', function (cell) {
                cell._cell.row.data.newRow = false;
                myClass.doSave();
            });
            this.aiTable.on('tableBuilt', function () {
            });
        }
        else {
            this.aiTable.replaceData(aiTableCopyTemp);
        }
    }

    doSave() {
        // how to do this in R Shiny will be the subject of another question
    }
}

const myClass = new AIClass();"

ui <- 
  htmltools::tagList(
    shinyjs::useShinyjs(),
    htmltools::tags$head(
      htmltools::tags$script(src = "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"), # is this needed?
      htmltools::tags$script(src = "https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.min.js"), # is this needed?
      htmltools::tags$link(rel = "stylesheet", type = "text/css", href = "https://unpkg.com/tabulator-tables@5.3.4/dist/css/tabulator.min.css"),
      htmltools::tags$link(rel = "stylesheet", type = "text/css", href = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tabulator/5.3.4/css/tabulator_bootstrap5.min.css"),
      htmltools::tags$script(src = "https://unpkg.com/tabulator-tables@5.3.4/dist/js/tabulator.min.js"),
      htmltools::tags$script(tabulatorClass)
    ),
    fluidPage(
      div(id = "tabulatorDiv")
    )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  # how to initialize and show Tabulator?
  # myClass.doLoad();
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 0):

After looking at latest Tabulator examples and SO questions about Tabulator & jQuery, I've modified the jQuery part and streamlined script imports. In RStudio, the script does show a Tabulator with the two sample data rows. The number and check box columns can be edited. Sorting works. And the after cell edit event fires.

[image: RStudio app window]

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

jQueryScript <- 
"$(document).ready(function() {
  const sampleData = [
      { AI: 'Substance2', AIGroup: 'GroupA', Volume: 1.23, Price: 4.56, Included: true },
      { AI: 'Substance1', AIGroup: 'GroupB', Volume: 3.21, Price: 6.54, Included: false },
  ];

  var table = new Tabulator('#tabulatorDiv', {
        columns: [
            { title: 'AI', field: 'AI', width: 150 },
            { title: 'AIGroup', field: 'AIGroup', width: 150 },
            { title: 'Volume', field: 'Volume', width: 100, editor: true },
            { title: 'Price', field: 'Price', width: 100, editor: true },
            { title: 'Included', field: 'Included', width: 100, hozAlign:'center', editor:true, formatter:'tickCross' },
        ],
        data: sampleData,
    });
    
  table.on('cellEdited', function (cell) {
    //alert() here breaks Tabulator events
    //alert(cell._cell.row.data);
  });
});"

ui <- 
  htmltools::tagList(
    shinyjs::useShinyjs(),
    htmltools::tags$head(
      htmltools::tags$link(rel = "stylesheet", type = "text/css", href = "https://unpkg.com/tabulator-tables@5.3.4/dist/css/tabulator.min.css"),
      htmltools::tags$script(src = "https://unpkg.com/tabulator-tables@5.3.4/dist/js/tabulator.min.js"),
      htmltools::tags$script(jQueryScript)
    ),
    fluidPage(
      div(id = "tabulatorDiv")
    )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
}

# browser console shows errors, which may be useful in debugging jQueryScript
# shinyApp(ui, server, options = list(launch.browser = TRUE))
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 0):

Now, for the second part: can Tabulator events be sent back to R?

Yes, they can. Tabulator data can be set from, say, a data frame via session$sendCustomMessage but it must be converted to JSON. Tabulator edit events can be sent back with something like Shiny.setInputValue. After that, observeEvent can trigger the R workload.

[image]

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

sampleDataDF <-
  data.frame(
    AI = c("Subst2", "Subst1", "X"),
    AIGroup = c("GrpA", "GrpB", "Z"),
    Volume = c(1.11, 2.22, 5),
    Price = c(4.44, 3.33, 6),
    Included = c(FALSE, FALSE, TRUE)
  )

sampleDataJson <- jsonlite::toJSON(sampleDataDF)

jQueryScript <- 
"$(document).ready(function() {
  var doLoad = function(data) {
    var table = new Tabulator('#tabulatorDiv', {
          columns: [
              { title: 'AI', field: 'AI', width: 150 },
              { title: 'AIGroup', field: 'AIGroup', width: 150 },
              { title: 'Volume', field: 'Volume', width: 100, editor: true },
              { title: 'Price', field: 'Price', width: 100, editor: true },
              { title: 'Included', field: 'Included', width: 100, hozAlign:'center', editor:true, formatter:'tickCross' },
          ],
          data: data,
      });
      
    table.on('cellEdited', function (cell) {
      if (`${cell._cell.initialValue}` != `${cell._cell.value}`) {
        const colName = cell._cell.column.field;
        const colID = cell._cell.row.data.AI; // AI or another ID column
        
        Shiny.setInputValue('txtID', colID);
        Shiny.setInputValue('txtColumn', colName);
        Shiny.setInputValue('txtValue', cell.getValue());
      }
    });
  }

  Shiny.addCustomMessageHandler('updateTabulatorData', function(arg) {
    doLoad(arg);
  });
});"

ui <- 
  htmltools::tagList(
    shinyjs::useShinyjs(),
    htmltools::tags$head(
      htmltools::tags$link(rel = "stylesheet", type = "text/css", href = "https://unpkg.com/tabulator-tables@5.3.4/dist/css/tabulator.min.css"),
      htmltools::tags$script(src = "https://unpkg.com/tabulator-tables@5.3.4/dist/js/tabulator.min.js"),
      htmltools::tags$script(jQueryScript)
    ),
    fluidPage(
      div(id = "tabulatorDiv"),
      shinyjs::hidden(
        textInput(inputId = "txtID", label = "ID", value = ""),
        textInput(inputId = "txtColumn", label = "COLUMN", value = ""),
        textInput(inputId = "txtValue", label = "VALUE", value = "")
      )
    )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  # passed data must be JSON
  session$sendCustomMessage("updateTabulatorData", sampleDataJson)

  observeEvent( input$txtValue , {
    if (input$txtID == "" && input$txtColumn == "" && input$txtValue == "")
      print("INIT")
    else {
      print("Do single UPDATE query of column name, new value:")
      print( paste("AI:", input$txtID) )
      print( input$txtColumn )
      print( input$txtValue )
    }
  })  
}

# browser console shows errors, which may be useful in debugging jQueryScript
# shinyApp(ui, server, options = list(launch.browser = TRUE))
shinyApp(ui, server)
```